# Как сохранять фотографии, отправленные боту в Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Недавно задался вопросом, связанным с тем, как можно сохранять фотографии, отправленные ботом? Что-то на подобие сервиса Imgur.

1. Человек отправляет фотографию боту
2. Бот загружает её в сетевую папку
3. Генерирует для неё название и отправляет обратно человеку ссылку

У такого способа есть плюс. Telegram сам сжимает фотографию. Я находил [подобный скрипт](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/issues/386), но он на PHP, а я вообще его не знаю и предпочитаю для работы Python. В качестве библиотеки использовал [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI). Есть какие либо идеи?

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def photo(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo)-1].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    src = "/var/www/share"+file_info.file_path
    with open(src, "wb") as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    bot.reply_to(message, "https:/site.com/" + src.strip("/var/www/share"))
```